# Event Listener on Element/document height in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i need an event listener for changes on document.body (offsetHeight, clientHeight etc.) in pur javascript (no jquery etc.)

should work in ff, safari, chrome, IE9,8,7

have anybody ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such thing is not possible directly.

The most simple way around is applying timer that will run constantly (using `setInterval`) and compare the current height with the previous height.

Shouldn't be hard to implement, will bring some quick example if you like though.